# gnuplot style index plotting using numpy and matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, gnuplot

I have been using gnuplot for as long as I remember.
Recently i have been wanting to switch to matplotlib.

One basic function of gnuplot i frequently use is the 'index' function.

Suppose I have the following data file (foo.dat):

```
1 1
2 2
3 3


1 1
2 4
3 9
```

I could do:

```
plot 'foo.dat' index 0 u 1:2
replot 'foo.dat' index 1 u 1:2
```

to get two lines corresponding to the two data sets in the same plot.
How would one import such a file using numpy and plot it using matplotlib?

Here is how I would like my final plot to look like:
[image]

Comment: Seems like there is no direct way to mimic gnuplot'a block indexing with some options. See [Reading data blocks from a file in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10512026/2604213) for a very similar question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `genfromtxt` to read in the file:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.genfromtxt('foo.dat')
```

gives:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  1.],
       [ 2.,  4.],
       [ 3.,  9.]])
```

Then plot:

```
plt.plot(a[3:,0],a[3:,1],marker='x',color='g')
plt.plot(a[0:3,0],a[0:3,1],marker='x',color='r')
```

gives:
[image]

**EDIT**

Following @Cristoph's comment

To read in *automatically*, you could split the file into chunks, if you read in with `pandas`. But you'd need to write a script to find the rows to skip for a large file.

```
import pandas as pd
b=pd.read_csv('foo.dat',sep=' ',chunksize=3,header=None,skiprows=(3,4),index_col=0)
for c in b:
    plt.plot(c)
```

Note the `skiprows` parameter - you'd need to create a list to fit your file if it's longer.

Comment: This is not exactly what I want. I have edited my question to add a figure of what i want.

Comment: The important point is, that gnuplot uses the two empty lines to *automatically* recognize different blocks, which can then be accessed with `index`.

Comment: That's not automatic, you must still give concrete numbers. You cannot say: plot the first two blocks, no matter how many points each contains, which is what gnuplot does...

Comment: @Christoph In that case the long answer to gforce89's comment is "yes, but you need to write a script to find the spaces between blocks."