# Python: Parsing Textfile into Blocks

Tags: python, python-2.7, parsing, text-files

I'm using the below example from [Reading data blocks from a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512026/reading-data-blocks-from-a-file-in-python) but I'm having issues, it is always ignoring the first block of text from the text file.

I've made some changes to the script from the one in the original SO question and it runs but always starts by returning the second block in the text file followed by the third block, the first block is never returned.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
def read_blocks(input_file, i, j):
    empty_lines = 0
    blocks = []
    for line in open(input_file):
        # Check for empty/commented lines
        if not line or line == '\n':
            # If 1st one: new block
            if empty_lines == 0:
                blocks.append([])
                blocks[-1].append(line)
            empty_lines += 1
        # Non empty line: add line in current(last) block
        else:
            empty_lines = 0
            blocks[-1].append(line)
    return blocks[i:j + 1]

for block in read_blocks("C:\\test_file.txt", 1, 1):
    print '-> block'
    for line in block:
        print line
```

**Text File**

```
Block: 1
Block: 1.2
Block: 1.3

Block: 2
Block: 2.1
Block: 2.2
Block: 2.3

Block: 3
Block: 3.1
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All sorted, turns out it was a silly mistake. I was passing 1 through to `read_blocks` for parameter `i` which was ignoring block '0', the fix was:

```
for block in read_blocks("C:\\test_file.txt", 0, 1):
    print '-> block'
    for line in block:
        print line
```